# Posts should be under the categories in array, MYSQL JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I can't tell what I want but i can show:

This is my query:

```
select categories.name 
     , posts.url
     , posts.name as postname 
  from categories 
  LEFT 
  JOIN posts 
    ON categories.id=post.category 
 where posts.home=1 
   and posts.view=1 
 order 
    by categories.position
     , posts.position
```

It is coming like this:

```
 [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Cars
                [url] => best-cars
                [postname] => Top 10 Cars in 2018
            )
[1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Cars
                [url] => lorem-ipsum-dolor-1
                [postname] => Lorem ipsum dolor 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => Places
                [url] => best-places-in-newyork
                [postname] => Top 10 Places in New York
            )
[3] => Array
            (
                [name] => Places
                [url] => lorem-ipsum-dolor-2
                [postname] => Lorem ipsum dolor 2
            )
```

But I want it like this:

```
        ["Cars"] => Array
            (
                [url] => best-cars
                [postname] => Top 10 Cars in 2018
            )

        ["Places"] => Array
            (
                [url] => best-places-in-newyork
                [postname] => Top 10 Places in New York
            )
```

How can i do that? I want this because there is many posts in one category. I want list category name and all posts under this category. Thanks.

Comment: This is an INNER JOIN btw

Comment: What if there are two cars? or places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `name` column as the array index in the result.

```
$result = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result[$row['name']] = array('url' => $row['url'], 'postname' => $row['postname']);
}
```

Note that your desired result can only have one post for each category, even if there are multiple posts in the database, because array keys can't be repeated. You should consider making the value of each category an array of posts rather than just a single post. In the above code, the change would be:

```
    $result[$row['name']][] = array('url' => $row['url'], 'postname' => $row['postname']);
```